# матричное умножение с cuda

Tags: c++, c, cuda

`cuda` отличная вещь, которая позваляет переносить на видеокарту разнообразные сложные вычисления, которые до этого могли выполняться только на `cpu` или приходилось кое-как писать вычислительные шейдеры на `opengl`. Меня же интересует есть ли у `cuda` возможность (стандартная для шейдеров) перемножение матриц и векторов? Понятно, что можно без проблем запилить это дело вручную, но, учитывая что это основная операция на видеокартах, я предполагаю, что в `cuda` есть для этого функционал.

Comment: https://www.shodor.org/media/content/petascale/materials/UPModules/matrixMultiplication/moduleDocument не это ли?

Comment: полезно, спасибо